# Image beside div - float overlap

Tags: html, css

I want to position a few small images beside a div and margin them correclty instead of being overlapped by the *emphasized text*center-div.

JSFiddle Demo:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/k7gLfeuc/`
```

The Problem is: When I scale the browser-window, the images disappear behind the "center"-div instead of margin to it.
Both Navigation-Div and Center-Div are margin pretty well to each other. But the images wont.
I tried it already with "clear:left/right/both", but with no success.

What am I doing wrong? I just want the images left to the center-div to margin correctly to the center-div.

Than you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need? live demo http://jsfiddle.net/k7gLfeuc/2/

Add below to your existing code:

```
#side {
    left:0;
    width: 19%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```